# UITableViewCell row height

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any such method or solution to auto adjust row height of tableview depending on content.I mean that I don't want to specify row height and want row height according to content of the row.If there is no such method then tell me the solution that how can I change height when the orientation of the device changes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to find the the height of the your content and can use it

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return "your content height + your padding height value";
 }
```

On orientation change just reload your table view thats it;

Comment: I know this method very well and used this many times.Read my question carefully.

Comment: but how woud I calculate height of row for different orientation ?

Comment: you don't have to calculate the height of row its the content height you have to take care and whenever the tableview will reload data it will fire the above delegate too and as you have passed your content height your cell height will be according to it only.

Answer (score 2):

check this out

```
// --dynamic cell height according to the text--
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  NSString *text = <your text>;
  CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(210, 20000.0f); 
  CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 
  // constratins the size of the table row according to the text

  CGFloat height = MAX(size.height,60);

  return height + (15);
  // return the height of the particular row in the table view
}
```

hope this helps

**EDIT** for the orientation have you tried this method?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    return YES;
}
```

or else if your table cells are custom with labels and imageviews etc then you can use setAutoresizingMask:  on each to auto adjust to orientations.

```
[yourview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

delegate method of UITableView.

You should be able to find plenty of tutorials about it if you google it.

Here's one for example:

http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/

Comment: I know this method very well and used this many times.Read my question carefully.

Comment: Ok, i didn't realize you were looking for something else.. However, i still think that this is the method you should be using.. even when the orientation changes, you can redraw your table and adjust your cells according to the new table's dimensions.

Comment: If I redraw table and all the time look to calculate height then it will take too much time to reload..that's the problem!!!

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't know what your tableView consists of but it shouldn't really be noticeable..

Answer (score 0):

You HAVE to use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Yea - I know you know this method very well, and I have read your question carefully.

1. You have to use that delegate method to dynamically control the height of the rows.  My suggestion is to examine the content at each cell from your backend data model for the tableview and return a number that is appropriate for that cell something like:

`NSDictionary *thisCell = (NSDictionary *)[myArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];`

```
NSString *myCellContents = [thisCell valueForKey:@"MyStringIWantToCheckOut"];

if ([mycellContents length] > 25) {        
    return 80; 
} else {        
    return 40;
}
```

1. As far as when orientation changes, you would have to do that in the delegate method:

   `-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

and then fire `reloadData` on the `TableView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (indexPath.row){
        case 0:
            if(indexPath.section == 0)
                //title 
                return  75;
        default:
            return 75;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**func tableView(_ heightForRowAttableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }**

for dynamic height for row otherwise you can give static height instead of "UITableViewAutomaticDimension"